# "Prohibited package name: java.util" on Class.forName("java.util...") in applet

Tags: java, reflection, applet, securityexception

I have an applet that references 2 signed jars:

- myapplet.jar
- jackson-all-1.9.9.jar

When starting the applet the second time (first time is without errors), I get this:

```
Exception in thread "thread applet-main.MyApplet-1"
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
              at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider.<init>(StdDeserializerProvider.java:81)
              at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:398)
              at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:358)
              at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:328)
              at net.Remote.<init>(Remote.java:50)
              at main.Env.init(Env.java:44)
              at main.MyApplet.init(MyApplet.java:25)
              at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Prohibited package name: java.util
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(Unknown Source)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
              at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
              at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
              at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
              at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
              at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
              at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
              at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
              at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.<clinit>(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:74)
              ... 9 more
```

The line in question is the first one in the following try-catch block:

```
try {
    Class<?> key = Class.forName("java.util.ConcurrentNavigableMap");
    Class<?> value = Class.forName("java.util.ConcurrentSkipListMap");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Class<? extends Map<?,?>> mapValue = (Class<? extends Map<?,?>>) value;
    _mapFallbacks.put(key.getName(), mapValue);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) { // occurs on 1.5
}
```

A couple of things I do not understand:

- Why does my Java7 JVM not take it **out of its runtime library**? But rather
- Why does it **try to download `/java/util/ConcurrentNavigableMap.class`** from my server, which obviously fails with a `404`?
- <strike>As that fails, why does it **try to re-download `myapplet.jar` 25 times** in rapid succession, each time successfully (`200`), and each time returning the same jar file?</strike>

**Update** I'm not sure whether the 25 retries are caused by the class loader trying to load the class, it might be some other code trying to load a resource (which would still be odd, but not related to the `CurrentNavigableMap` issue), so I'll exclude that from my question.

N.B. I guess it does not try to re-download the jackson jar file, as that one is listed in the `cache_archive` attribute.

Comment: Are you sure you use java7? What happens if instead of Class.forName(), java.util.ConcurrentNavigableMap.class is used?

Comment: According to the Java Console that I meanwhile setup to start alongside applets: `1.7.0_07-b11 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM`

Comment: Launch it free floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It will get a fresh VM each time and that will likely solve the problem.  Then report the details of the error to Oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this?

wrong:

```
Class.forName("java.util.ConcurrentNavigableMap");
```

Correct:
http://java.sun.com/javase/ja/6/docs/ja/api/java/util/concurrent/package-tree.html

```
Class.forName("java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentNavigableMap");
```

Comment: Doh! I guess that's a bug in Jackson - will check with those guys.

Comment: Just sent a pull request to the Jackson guys: https://github.com/christophercurrie/jackson/pull/1